# Displaying PDFs in Android Browser

Tags: php, android, pdf, download

I would like to display a PDF file as a result of browsing to the following address:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/myfile
```

To that end I am using a 301 Redirect on `.htaccess` which redirects `myfile` to `myfile.php`. This file then contains

```
<?php
$filename = 'files/somefile.pdf';

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="somefile.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

@readfile($filename);
?>
```

The main idea is that the PDF is displayed in the browser without prompting the user for download, but that when forcing the download the output filename becomes `somefile.pdf`. Everything is working smoothly in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. However, in Android nothing happens. The PDF is not displayed and it doesn't prompt for download. How can I get this to work with Android? Is there anything I need to change in the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android native browser doesn't have PDF support. You will need to embed the your url with google doc. Try this one..hope it will help..

```
url="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://118.102.182.50/victor/testpdf.aspx?s=9";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```